# How to do Android's DigitalClock show the date?

Tags: android

When the mobile screen locks, its shown a time and date widget.
I'm trying to how it using DigitalClock, but I can show only time.
Any idea how to show date either (with this or other built-in widget)?

--update

I found some pages talking about alternatives to Android Calendar, but I don't find Android Calendar widget nowhere..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in widget to show the date, sorry.

Comment: Right now I put a static date there, which works for 99% of the cases fine. But if there is anything I can implement quickly: Let us know. How does your work around look like?